# Substituting the first occurrence of a pattern in a line, for all the lines in a file with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Is it possible to do it in one liner?

I have an output like this:

```
"First line" - Description  
" Second line" - Description  
"Third line" - Description  
" Fourth line" - Description
```

This input is generated automatically.

I want to replace the first occurrence of `"` (quotation mark + space) with `"` (quotation mark) for each line. If I apply the substitution globally, it will also change every occurrence of `line" -` to `line"-`, so I was wondering if it is possible to use a sed one liner to accomplish this.

I have tried using `^` like this

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/(\^\" )/\"/g'
```

But it's not working, it doesn't replace anything. I tried

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/(^|\" )/\"/g'
```

and it replaces all the occurrences. I've just started to use sed, so I don't really know if I'm doing something wrong.

What am I missing here?

Comment: A note about labels: The command you wrote above may work in some implementations of `sed`, but for portability and to avoid really weird errors, you should end a given command argument after a label (if you need them at all).  E.g., `sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 'whatever'`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're overthinking it.  `sed` replaces only the first instance on a line by default (without the `/g` modifier), although you still want to anchor because you don;t so much want the first instance in the line as the one at the start of the line; and you usually don't need the explicit line actions you're trying to use (why?).

```
sed 's/^" /"/'
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was necessary to explicitly declare the line actions when working on a file, read about it and just kept on using them. I really was over-thinking it, that couldn't be simpler and it does the trick :)

Comment: I'm tempted to say those commands are pretty much obsolete; it is possible to do quite complex multiline things with them, but it's not *easy* to do so and these days you're really better off using perl/python/ruby/whatever instead.

Comment: Completely disagree with the above comment; multi-line `sed` commands such as `N` and labels such as `:a` are not obsolete at all and they *are* portable [and POSIX specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), unlike Perl/Python/Ruby/whatever.  It is true however that if you find yourself *needing* them often, you should [learn `awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Answer (score 5):

A more general answer, since I can't comment on geekosaur's answer - You wouldn't put the ^ (start of line anchor).  For example, if you want to replace the first occurence of A with B, you would have

```
sed 's/A/B/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Perl**

```perl
~$ perl -pe 's/^" /"/;'   file
```

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/^\" \s /"/;'  file
```

---

Sample Input:

```
"First line" - Description  
" Second line" - Description  
"Third line" - Description  
" Fourth line" - Description
```

Sample Output (both code examples):

```
"First line" - Description  
"Second line" - Description  
"Third line" - Description  
"Fourth line" - Description
```

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre
https://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap#Sed-Traps
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes