# Add numbers at the beginning of each line and replace asterisks with numbers in a document

Tags: text-processing

Is there a way in Linux CentOS 7 to add numbers to the lines of a document. Any method is OK, command, code, script or whatever. I have a document, and I want to number the lines.

#### Input example

```
Only I can change my life.
Good, better, best.
Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it.
```

#### Output

```
1 Only I can change my life.
2 Good, better, best.
3 Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it.
```

### Another question

How can I change the asterisks "*" at the beginning of a text with numbers?

#### Input

```
* Only I can change my life.
* Good, better, best.
* Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it.
```

#### Output

```
1 Only I can change my life.
2 Good, better, best.
3 Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it.
```

Comment: Please focus on one question per Question, so that we can have good answers to each. Thank you!

Comment: @Jeff Schaller I am so sorry! just I am new to U&L and still don't know the rules!

Comment: Please detail whether all lines have a asterisk/star "*" at the beginning.  If not, do you wish to have numbers in the lines that do not have one?  (The current replies below assume that there are no lines without an asterisk/star, therefore they are just removed and line numbers added independently of *s.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To number *every* line, use [nl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl), the **N**umber **L**ines utility:

```
nl -ba input
```

The flag means: use a `b`ody numbering style of `a`ll lines.

To number only non-blank lines, use:

```
nl -bt input
```

`nl` provides a variety of features for formatting the numbers; by default, it separates the numbers with a tab; for a single space, use `-s' '`.  It also assumes a default column width for the numbers; if you don't want such padding space, use `-w 1`.

To replace leading characters with sed, see [Substituting the first occurrence of a pattern in a line, for all the lines in a file with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36033/substituting-the-first-occurrence-of-a-pattern-in-a-line-for-all-the-lines-in-a?rq=1), for example:

```
sed 's/^\*//' input
```

... where the `*` has to be escaped because it's a regular expression token meaning zero-or-more of the previous item. While there is no previous item (it's an anchor meaning beginning-of-the-line), it's a better habit to escape it.

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller thanks you very much, how can I replace the /*/ ?

Comment: AFAIK, the `*` does not have to be escaped if it's the first character in a regular expression (or occurs straight after the `^` anchor).

Comment: Agreed, @Kusalananda, though I had to test it to be sure -- but I'd rather encourage the habit of escape characters that you don't *intend* to be special.

Comment: Guess what, `s/^*//` without the backslash doesn't work in Perl. :) (and `s/*//` gives an error) Also, you might want to remove the following space (or spaces) too, especially if you add another with `nl -s " "`.

Answer (score 2):

To add numbers to a document:

```
cat -b file > output_file
-b, --number-nonblank    number nonempty output lines, overrides -n
```

To write a file to standard output, with line numbers added instead of asterisks.

```
cat file | sed 's/*//' | nl > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input:

Only I can change my life.
Good, better, best.
Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it


output:

[root@praveen_2 ~]# cat -n input
     1  Only I can change my life.
     2  Good, better, best.
     3  Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it.


command:cat -n input


=============================================================================
second questtion

input
* Only I can change my life.
* Good, better, best.
* Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it

output

cat -n input| sed 's/\*//g'
     1   Only I can change my life.
     2   Good, better, best.
     3   Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you react to it


command:cat -n input| sed 's/\*//g
```

'