# Extract first match in line with sed

Tags: sed

I have a series of lines form.

```
Agenda HR-1 Presented by XYZ
HR-2 Debate-1 - All
HR-3 Debate-2 - All
(Cov-4) Conclusion
```

Each line has an ID of the (sed) pattern `[A-Za-z]\+-[0-9]\+`, i.e. one or more alphabets follows by a dash (-) follows by one or more numbers. They occur anywhere in the line.

I need to extract the IDs. My thought was to stick a `.*` at the beginning and end and print `\1`, but I can't get it to work.

[This](http://%60https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36035/40620%60) reply says sed replaces the first match only and that is correct:

```
$ cat /tmp/scratch/x | sed -n   's/\<\([A-Za-z]\+-[0-9]\+\)/ID:\1/p'
Agenda ID:HR-1 Presented by XYZ
ID:HR-2 Debate-1 - All
ID:HR-3 Debate-2 - All
(ID:Cov-4) Conclusion
```

But of course a `.*` at start would greedily go to the last match:

```
$ cat /tmp/scratch/x | sed -n   's/.*\<\([A-Za-z]\+-[0-9]\+\).*/ID:\1/p'
ID:HR-1
ID:Debate-1
ID:Debate-2
ID:Cov-4
```

The only way I can think of doing this in `sed` is by adding markers around the ID in one command and extract using another, as follows.

Is there a better way to do this in sed?

```
$ cat x | sed -n   's/\<\([A-Za-z]\+-[0-9]\+\)/<id>\1<~id>/;s/.*<id>\(.*\)<~id>.*/\1/;p'
HR-1
HR-2
HR-3
Cov-4
```

Comment: You don't need to use `cat` with `sed`. `sed` already sends to stdout. Add the expected output to your questiion. Also, `ID` doesn't appear anywhere in the first block of your sample text.

Comment: Is sed your only option here? it would be quite straightforward in perl I think

Comment: @steeldriver I was able get it to work with `perl` by copying from an answer here but hesitated because I have never used perl much.

Comment: @nasir piping from cat is just a style choice in my example. In actual use the input comes from a different command. Not sure I understand your point about ID, I have used it in replacement text. Perhaps my not using it in the last example is the source of confusion?

Comment: @MiserableVariable You simply don't need to use it. If it's in the file `/tmp/scratch/x`, then just use `sed` with the file as an argument. Your first sample of text at the top of your question doesn't have `ID`.

Comment: @NasirRiley I am pretty sure you are reading this wrong. Regarding your concern about me using a `cat` and `pipe`, as I explained earlier (i) it is a style choice; but it is also very useful because it can be easily converted to any other command (ii) "our first sample of text at the top of your question doesn't have ID" correct. And again as I wrote earlier there is no "ID" in the input text, it is added by the `sed` command; note `"ID:\1"` in replacement text

Comment: @MiserableVariable I am not reading anything incorrectly. It's not even that big of a deal. If you want to use it due to style, then that's fine but I'm just remarking that it's unnecessary and redundant because using `sed` with the filename as an argument does the same exact same thing without having to use `cat`. If that's what you want to do, then that's up to you but I was just pointing it out. Carry on.

Comment: @NasirRiley my question was about your comment "Your first sample of text at the top of your question doesn't have ID". You are quite correct that it does not, but I could not understand its relevance.

You are quite correct that the cat is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk`, try:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+' '$1{print $1}' FILE
```

or:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+' '$0=$1' FILE
```

Comment: `gawk` is usually my tool of choice but haven't used `FPAT` in the longest time if at all. Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, try:

```
<FILE sed -En '/([[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+).*/{ s//:\1/; s/.*://p; }'
```

- Remove everything after the desired match
- Now the match is at the end of every line – this can be handled in various ways

  - The above is easily readable – place a `char` which isn't part of the the match before each match, then remove everything up to the last `char` with the second `s` command
  - Another option for the second `s` command is to remove everything up to a character which is not part of the match:

```
<FILE sed -En '/([[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+).*/{ s//\1/; s/.*[^[:alnum:]-]//; p; }'
```

Comment: Removing everything after the first match is an interesting approach. My current approach is also to use a delimiter not occurring in the ID, so that is something I can relate to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `Perl` we can do it as follows:

```
$ perl -lne 'print /([a-z]+-\d+)/i' file
```

**output**:

```
HR-1
HR-2
HR-3
Cov-4
```